# How to create multiple page app using react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack

I have created a single page web app using react js. I have used `webpack` to create bundle of all components. But now I want to create many other pages. Most of pages are API call related. i.e. in the `index.html`, I have displayed content from `API`. I want to insert content in another page parsing data from API. Webpack compresses everything of react in a file which is `bundle.js`. However, the configuration of `webpack` is as follow:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
entry: './main.js',

output: {
    path:'./',
    filename: 'dist/bundle.js',
},

devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 3000
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    })
]
}

module.exports = config;
```

Now, I am confused what kind of configuration of `webpack` will be for other page or what is the correct way to build multi-pages app using `react.js`

Comment: you can have multiple output files for each page that you want in your application.

Comment: Let me include some context here, by default `npm run build` creates a static index.html, the static nature which is important here for making a static read only hosting website, now generally websites have an about page, page1, page2 etc, which can be very large text/image pages, the entire bundle in single index.html hurts loading time and responsiveness of the site on a slow connection or device, so how do we split up the output pages into individual pages to help with responsiveness

Answer (score 91):

### Preface

This answer uses the [dynamic routing](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/philosophy) approach embraced in `react-router` v4+. [Other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41970301/5432315) may reference the previously-used "static routing" approach that has been [abandoned](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/philosophy) by `react-router`.

### Solution

[`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) is a great solution. You create your pages as Components and the router swaps out the pages according to the current URL. In other words, it replaces your original page with your new page dynamically instead of asking the server for a new page.

For web apps I recommend you read these two things first:

- [Full Tutorial](https://blog.pusher.com/getting-started-with-react-router-v4/)
- The [react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start); it will help you get a better understanding of how Router works.

#### Summary of the general approach:

**1 -** Add `react-router-dom` to your project:

**Yarn**

```
yarn add react-router-dom
```

or **NPM**

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

**2 -** Update your `index.js` file to something like:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App /> {/* The various pages will be displayed by the `Main` component. */}
  </BrowserRouter>
  ), document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**3 -** Create a `Main` component that will show your pages according to the current URL:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Signup from '../pages/Signup';

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Switch> {/* The Switch decides which component to show based on the current URL.*/}
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}></Route>
      <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup}></Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

**4 -** Add the `Main` component inside of the `App.js` file:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**5 -** Add `Link`s to your pages.

(You must use `Link` from `react-router-dom` instead of just a plain old `<a>` in order for the router to work properly.)

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
...
<Link to="/signup">
  <button variant="outlined">
    Sign up
  </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: Works great however, 
Add a line in section no. 1 e.g. import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom'
Plus use useHistory to move from one screen to another programmatically.

Comment: Note that from react-router-dom v6 Switch has been replaced by Routes

Comment: Note that `component={Home}` has been replaced by `element={<Home/>}` in v6 (step 3).

Answer (score 75):

(Make sure to install react-router using npm!)

To use react-router, you do the following:

1. Create a file with **routes** defined using Route, IndexRoute components
2. Inject the **Router** (with 'r'!) component as the top-level component for your app, passing the routes defined in the routes file and a type of history (hashHistory, browserHistory)
3. Add **{this.props.children}** to make sure new pages will be rendered there
4. Use the **Link** component to change pages

**Step 1**
*routes.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

/**
 * Import all page components here
 */
import App from './components/App';
import MainPage from './components/MainPage';
import SomePage from './components/SomePage';
import SomeOtherPage from './components/SomeOtherPage';

/**
 * All routes go here.
 * Don't forget to import the components above after adding new route.
 */
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={MainPage} />
    <Route path="/some/where" component={SomePage} />
    <Route path="/some/otherpage" component={SomeOtherPage} />
  </Route>
);
```

**Step 2** *entry point (where you do your DOM injection)*

```
// You can choose your kind of history here (e.g. browserHistory)
import { Router, hashHistory as history } from 'react-router';
// Your routes.js file
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router routes={routes} history={history} />,
  document.getElementById('your-app')
);
```

**Step 3** *The App component* (props.children)

In the render for your App component, add {this.props.children}:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        This is my website!
      </header>

      <main>
        {this.props.children}
      </main>

      <footer>
        Your copyright message
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Step 4** *Use Link for navigation*

Anywhere in your component render function's return JSX value, use the  Link component:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
(...)
<Link to="/some/where">Click me</Link>
```

Comment: I am confused a a beginner here. Isn't react-router for single page apps? I mean, if you have one index.html file then only that is going to be a page? Others will be injected as in single paged apps right?

Comment: This is not Multipage app in webpack. If you had more than 1 entry then you have multi page app (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application)

Comment: How could I share state between these different page components?

Comment: @robinmetral use something like Redux. Or you could just have a parent component hold the data, then you pass it down to the multiple routes under it (this is a concept called "Container" component).

Comment: Thank you @nbkhope! I'll look up container components. I found [a good series here](https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-container-components/) if anyone's interested :)

Comment: `Attempted import error: 'hashHistory' is not exported from 'react-router' (imported as 'history').`

Answer (score 12):

This is a broad question and there are multiple ways you can achieve this. In my experience, I've seen a lot of single page applications having an entry point file such as `index.js`. This file would be responsible for 'bootstrapping' the application and will be your entry point for webpack.

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Application from './components/Application';

const root = document.getElementById('someElementIdHere');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Application />,
  root,
);
```

Your `<Application />` component would contain the next pieces of your app. You've stated you want different pages and that leads me to believe you're using some sort of routing. That could be included into this component along with any libraries that need to be invoked on application start. `react-router`, `redux`, `redux-saga`, `react-devtools` come to mind. This way, you'll only need to add a single entry point into your webpack configuration and everything will trickle down in a sense.

When you've setup a router, you'll have options to set a component to a specific matched route. If you had a URL of `/about`, you should create the route in whatever routing package you're using and create a component of `About.js` with whatever information you need.

Answer (score 7):

Following on from the answer above by @lucas-andrade: for `react-router` versions >= 6, `Switch` no longer exists (see https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8439). The content of step 3 becomes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Signup from '../pages/Signup';

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={Home}></Route>
      <Route path='/signup' element={Signup}></Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 2):

The second part of your question is answered well. Here is the answer for the first part: How to output multiple files with `webpack`:

```
{
    entry: {
        outputone: './source/fileone.jsx',
        outputtwo: './source/filetwo.jsx'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './wwwroot/js/dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'      
    },
}
```

This will generate 2 files: `outputone.js` and `outputtwo.js` in the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use [gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) a react framework dedicated to static multipage apps.