# Is there a way to link a javascript to html in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, dom

So I've been working on a react website whose file system is like this:

- public:

  - index.html
  - second.html
- src:

  - index.js
  - second.js
  - table.js
  - forms.js

So I have a form and a table in the main page (index.js). One of the columns in the table contains the link to access the second page. And the second.html should be linked with second.js. I tried using

`<script src="second.js></script>`

on the HTML page but it didn't work. I even tried ../src/second.js in the script tag. Can anyone point out what is the problem here and what can be done about it?

Thank you

Comment: i really wanted to help unblock you but i couldn't understand what you meant. I think you should edit the question and make it more understandable. #cheers

Comment: Could you expose some code to show us how you handled it? You are talking about routes, so please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to use a second HTML page within react (dont take my word for it, i'm not sure), but if you are trying to create multiple pages you need to look at react-router. Here is a link to help you out. [How to create multiple page app using react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956465/how-to-create-multiple-page-app-using-react) .