# How do I add pages in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to web development but I've built a website using react and I can't figure out how to add a page to it. Do I add it in app.js or do I need another file? Are there any examples that can explain this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956465/how-to-create-multiple-page-app-using-react

Comment: This 3 part tutorial really helped me out when I was a novice react coder. https://www.techandstartup.com/tutorials/build-api-with-node-express-and-mongodb

It covers everything needed included adding pages. and routes

Answer (score 1):

For adding a page, You need to install and use the `react-router-dom` in your react application.

Initially, You need to install `react-router-dom`. Run a below command to install the same,

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

Then configure the routing in App.js. Each route defines a seperate page. The `Layout` route alone will be in the top layer. That is for Layout setup. We will wrapping all the routes inside the `Layout` route and in the Layout component we will be providing  where the contents of `Home` and `About` will be displayed.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Components/Home'
import About from './Components/About'
import Layout from './Components/Layout'


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Layout.jsx**

```
import { Outlet, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <>

            <Link to="/">Home</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            <Outlet />
        </>
    )
}
```

**Home.jsx**

```
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>

            <p>This is Home</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

**About.jsx**

```
export default function About() {
    return (
        <>
            <p>This is About Us</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create components or separate pages based on your requirement. For routing-related stuff, you can use react-router-dom https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start.

**Example :**

**App.js**

```
    import React from "react";
    import {
      BrowserRouter as Router,
      Switch,
      Route,
      Link
    } from "react-router-dom";
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <div>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
    
            {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
                renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/about">
                <About />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/users">
                <Users />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }
```

**Home.js**

```
function Home() {
          return <h2>Home</h2>;
}
```

**About.js**

```
function About() {
      return <h2>About</h2>;
}
```

**Users.js**

```
 function Users() {
      return <h2>Users</h2>;
 }
```